# Is there a difference between permission_classes = [A, B], permission_classes = [A & B]?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

What is the difference between

```
permission_classes = [A, B] 
permission_classes = [A & B]
```

??

I understand that the first one processes permission sequentially, and the second one does it at once.

Is there a difference in the result?

Also, I wonder which method is preferred and why.

Comment: The first is a Python `list` with two items `A` and `B`, while the second (also a `list`) only contains one item, the result of the unary operation `A & B`

Comment: @JRiggles: yes, but for the the algebra of Django's permission classes, these are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short**: two or more elements in a list or tuple is advisable.

Semantically the two are *nearly* the same. Indeed, Django checks the permissions in the [**`.check_permissions(…)`** method <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8b7e6f2e3405d6e71488db53f2dda515d5a336c6/rest_framework/views.py#L326-L337):

> ```
> def check_permissions(self, request):
>     """
>     Check if the request should be permitted.
>     Raises an appropriate exception if the request is not permitted.
>     """
>     for permission in self.get_permissions():
>         if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
>             self.permission_denied(
>                 request,
>                 message=getattr(permission, 'message', None),
>                 code=getattr(permission, 'code', None),
>             )
> ```

It thus enumerates over the items in the list and when one of the permissions fails, it invokes the `.permission_denied(…)` method with the message and code of the permission that failed.

If you use the `&` operator on the other hand, it will construct a new permission, with the [**`.__and__(…)`** method <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8b7e6f2e3405d6e71488db53f2dda515d5a336c6/rest_framework/permissions.py#L11-L13):

> ```
> class OperationHolderMixin:
>     def __and__(self, other):
>         return OperandHolder(AND, self, other)
>
>
> # …
>
>
> class OperandHolder(OperationHolderMixin):
>     def __init__(self, operator_class, op1_class, op2_class):
>         self.operator_class = operator_class
>         self.op1_class = op1_class
>         self.op2_class = op2_class
>
>     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         op1 = self.op1_class(*args, **kwargs)
>         op2 = self.op2_class(*args, **kwargs)
>         return self.operator_class(op1, op2)
>
>     # …
>
>
> class AND:
>     def __init__(self, op1, op2):
>         self.op1 = op1
>         self.op2 = op2
>
>     def has_permission(self, request, view):
>         return self.op1.has_permission(request, view) and self.op2.has_permission(
>             request, view
>         )
>
>     def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
>         return self.op1.has_object_permission(
>             request, view, obj
>         ) and self.op2.has_object_permission(request, view, obj)
> ```

This is thus essentially just some meta-programming logic to first run the `.has_permission(…)` on the first operand and if that succeeds, on the second operand.

So it seems that the two are equivalent? Well not exactly, by using an `&`, the `.message` and `.code` are gone, so one can not trace back which permission check exactly has been denied. While most (all) builtin permissions have no message or code, if you thus specify one yourself for a custom permission check, and that permission check is used in an operator, the result of that expression loses the code and message.

So while this is likely, a small detail, there is a small advantage in using `[perm1, perm2]` over `[perm1 & perm2]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
permission_classes = [A, B] # User has both A and B
permission_classes = [A & B] # User has both A and B
permission_classes = [A | B] # User either A or B
```

Choose the one that fits best in your specific situation or coding style.